# The angular material dialog is not working in production build

Tags: angular-material, angular10

I am using angular 10 and angular material 10.
the angular material dialogue is not working in the production build (`ng serve --prod` and `ng build --prod`) but It is working fine local dev environment (`ng serve`)

1. I have already added the component in the `entryComponents`  and `bootstrap`
2. It is not throwing any kind of error in the console. what I can see is the card is loaded and no components inside the dialog are available,
3. You can see the below screenshot, which is loading the card but not any component inside it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I found, the problem is with the IVY engine. For some people changing the below can solve the problem. 
**tsconfig.json**

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": true
  },
```

If you want to use the Ivy engine. the problem will be resolved if you update the Angular 10 project to Angular 11.